# Html formatting pdf template

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Im trying to format names cause it produce unknown symbols but the problem is my code doesn't work.
can you suggest any ways to solve this ? thanks in advance.

```
$accountBean = BeanFactory::getBean('Accounts', $subscriptionBean->accounts_fp_subscriptions_1accounts_ida);
        $row['subscription_no'] = !empty($subscriptionBean->subscription_no) ? $subscriptionBean->subscription_no : '';
        $row['full_name'] = !empty($subscriptionBean->full_name) ? trim($subscriptionBean->full_name) : '';
        $row['total_due'] = !empty($subscriptionBean->balance_amount_c) ? $subscriptionBean->balance_amount_c : '0.00';
        $row['current_due'] = $this->getCurrentDue($subscriptionBean);

    if($accountBean == 'varchar') {
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("account bean");
        $accountBean->full_name = html_entity_decode($row->$accountBean[full_name]);
        }
```

Comment: can you add complete detail like what unknown characters it contains and how you tried to fix it? And what is not working according to your expectation?

Comment: if($accountBean == 'varchar') what you want achieve using this condition?